# Utilize a machine learning model -- finding a vector that has the smallest L2 distance to a given vector after projecting both to a specific space?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, machine-learning

We are building an online service where users can try our model. Our model assigns a different embedding vector for each entity. User would like to query for the entity $t$ that has the lowest scoring function:
$$
|| h \times M_r + r  - t \times M_r ||^2_2
$$
Where $h, r, t \in \mathbb{R}^{1024}$, and $M_r$ is the projection matrix, in our case, a diagonal matrix $M_r \in \mathbb{R}^{1024 * 1024}$.

In the training process, we calculate the score for every possible entity and see if some entities have the lowest score, which takes about 5 seconds on our machine. But we want to build an online service, so taking 5 seconds serving a single request isn't acceptable.

There are tools, such as faiss, which can quickly find the top k vectors from a large set of vectors that have the smallest L2 distance from a given query vector. Is there any way to use this tool to speed up our query time?

Comment: If you apply the projection to each vector in $E$ and make a list of all the resulting projected vectors, you get a new set of vectors, $E'$. Now you have tools to find the vector $u$ in $E'$ satisfying that $u$ has the smallest distance with $h$. Now if you can figure out which $t$ in $E$ produced the vector $u$ in $E'$ you have your answer, right?

Comment: Yes @DavidK. The problem is that there are about 5M vectors in $E$.

Comment: So projecting all vector in E to make $E'$ isn't possible.

Comment: My basic idea is to find a vector $t'$ satisfying that the order of vectors in $E$ measured by L2 distance is the same as the order of vectors after projected to $E'$. Then I can use $t'$ to find the closest vector.

Comment: This is on a computer, right? Surely it is possible to project five million vectors. It just might take a while, depending on how many components are in each vector. On the other hand, the vector $t'$ you plan to use does not exist for every set $E$ and every transformation matrix $M$. That is what I would say "isn't possible."

Comment: $E$ takes about 18G of memory, and we have about 2k different $M$s. Storing then all, either in memory or in disk, isn't possible due to our resourses.

Comment: What if the transformation matrix $M$ is a diagonal matrix? i.e. the projecting operation is just an element-wise product?

Comment: Any projection can be diagonalized, so no, making the matrix diagonal doesn't force $t'$ to exist. I gather you have on the order of $4000$ components in a vector, so a full conversion is expensive, but you only need $36$ GB (of which $18$ GB will be overwritten $2000$ times in order to repeat the process for each $M.$) Now if you want to repeat the process for several different vectors $t$ with the same set $E$ and the same set of matrices $M$, constantly recalculating $E'$ will wast a lot of time. How much time? You could do benchmarks to estimate it.

Comment: You might have a better question if you included all of the information about the dimensions of the vectors, the number of vectors, and the number of times you must do a similar calculation. Also any facts about the possible vector $t$, the set $E$, and the matrix $M$ (such as that it is diagonal, if it is) that might lead to a more efficient method. The first thing that comes to my mind is to wonder whether the existing tools allow you to specify a modified distance function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134111/discussion-between-leo-lu-and-david-k).